# Capture Mouse event and register it as a Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was going through [`chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html#event-onCommand) event that helps me to define specific commands and bind it to a key combination.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature-foo": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
      },
      "description": "Toggle feature foo"
    },
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
      }
    },
    "_execute_page_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+E"
        "windows": "Alt+P",
        "mac": "Option+P",
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

My question is, how can I bind a key combination to register another key combination instead of launching browser_action.html as the [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html#samples) shows.

For example: I want to register Ctrl+P by [Mouse Middle Click + P] instead.